# EJS marker is out of function

Tags: html, node.js, ejs, atom-editor

Dear stack overflow community,
I am trying to put a EJS marker into my list.ejs file and I would need to achieve this - (this first image is taken from a video tutorial)

[image: Desired outcome]

But in my case, I am encountering this problem

[image: -]

EJS marker is just a plain text, but at first <%= %> was working, (although it was violet and not red) but it was turning all of the subsequent closing html tags (h1, body and html) into a plain text. So then I tried to uncheck the Use Tree Sitter Parsers option inside Atom's settings like below

[image: -]

and this changed my first problem into the one, which I am trying to solve right now, which You can see on the picture, where my EJS marker is just a plain text, but the subsequential closing html tags are working again. I tried to check that Use Tree Sitter Parsers option again and then restart Atom, but the EJS marker remained the same as if I didn't check that option again, but I did. I hope, that this is understandable. If not, then take into account, that this is my first question on stack overflow, so please be patient with me. I will try to be more precise in my next posts. I would really appreciate Your help.

P.S. I have installed the EJS module correctly and I have included it in my app.js -

`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

I am using Node.js and Node Package Manager and I have created my app constant by using Express.js -

`const app = express();`

Comment: It's better if you could add the codes using the `code` tags with out using images. It would make people who are willing to help you look more.

Comment: So the problem is just that Atom incorrectly displays the ejs-tags? Have you installed https://atom.io/packages/language-ejs?

Comment: I have used images instead of comments because of the colors in order present this issue more distinctly. I am not sure, where is the root of this problem, but I have installed the language-ejs package for Atom.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have EJS grammar selected in the bottom right hand corner of Atom. It might be set to HTML grammar instead, change it by clicking it and scrolling through the menu that pops up.